# How does DROP TRIGGER work in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about how DROP TRIGGER works.

I used this command to drop triggers:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `database`.`mytrigger`;
```

But my qquestion is, u can drop a trigger selecting it with  table name? for example:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `table`.`mytrigger`;
```

I tried it but the trigger is not deleted when i set tablename.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because that doesn't uniquely identify a trigger, and it ends up looking like you're trying to say you have a database called `table` anyway. If you just want to leave off the database name, you don't need to replace it with anything:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mytrigger`;
```

Comment: So, if Im automatically creating a trigger on each table to save the update date of a row (for example updated_date_trigger), I should add also the name of the table (mytable_updated_date_trigger)?

Comment: Yes. SQL scopes most object names, including triggers and keys, to the database, so a sensible naming scheme should include the name of the table they belong to. (Only exception I can think of offhand is columns.)

Answer (score 5):

Triggers don't exist at the table level. They are database level objects that are just associated with tables. There is no means to delete them by related table.

Comment: So, if Im automatically creating a trigger on each table to save the update date of a row (for example updated_date_trigger), I should add also the name of the table (mytable_updated_date_trigger)?

Comment: I certainly seems to be a reasonable naming scheme to include the related table name in the name of the trigger.

Comment: *There is no means to delete them by related table.* well, dropping the table is a means to drop the trigger :) albeit outside the question's context.